# How to make option tag in HTML display rows of one column but save values of another from the same table

Tags: html, forms, flask-sqlalchemy, html-select, pythonanywhere

I am trying to make a calorie counter app using flask/python-anywhere, and part of it is making a drop down menu of foods to choose from. I want the user to be able to see the food name, but when they submit the food, it's the food's **calories** that I want to be added to the database.

This is the python code for the relevant tables:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    calories = db.Column(db.Integer)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.now)
    consumer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)
    consumer = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=consumer_id)

class Food(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "foods"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    food_name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    food_cal = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

This is the python code for the page:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html", foods=Food.query.all(), posts=Post.query.all(), timestamp=datetime.now())
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    add_food = Post(calories=request.form["calories"], consumer=current_user)
    db.session.add(add_food)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

and this is my html code:

```
<div class="container">
            {% for post in posts %}
                <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1ex">
                    <div>
                        You added {{ post.calories }} calories
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <small>
                            at
                            {% if post.timestamp %}
                                {{ post.timestamp.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y at %H:%M") }}
                            {% else %}
                                at an unknown time
                            {% endif %}
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                <div class="row">
                    <form action="." method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="foods">Food:</label>
                            <select class="form control" name="food_name">
                                {% for food in foods %}
                                    <option value = "{{ food.food_name }}" selected>{{ food.food_name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}    
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add calories">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div><!-- /.container -->
```

Just to clarify, the foods in the Food table have been added on my end, but I want the foods that users select to be saved as 'calories' in my Post table. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option value = "{{ food.food_name }}" selected>{{ food.food_name }}</option>
```

should be

```
<option value = {{ food.food_cal }} selected>{{ food.food_name }}</option>
```